# Why does Python treats datatype keywords like (int) as variables?

Tags: python

for instance, if I want to store `5` in a variable named `int`, I am able to do it. However, in statically typed languages like C/C++, I can't use datatype names as variables. **Why is that not the case in python?**

```
int = 5
print(int)
```

> `5`

I am also able to do the same with `list/tuple/dict` keywords.

Comment: ```int``` can do its thing only when there is ```()```, other wise, it is just referenced. I think python doesn't recognise a function until it is called. So it can allow the user to assign value to data type

Comment: Python only restricts you for reserved keywords, you can't say `while = 5` or `class = 5`

Comment: Syntactically, the difference is that in C, data types like ```int``` are keywords. In Python, the built-in types are predefined objects; since they aren't keywords, the names can be redefined.

Answer (score 2):

Python has a set of [built-in functions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html). When you redefine `int` you're simply overwriting the global symbol. This is as opposed to a [reservered keyword](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#keywords) which gives a `SyntaxError` if you try to redefine it.